# Can someone explain atan2 with a visual explanation?

Tags: trigonometry, angle

I'm trying to find the direction of a moving object and I came across the concept of using atan2 to do this (if the angle is > 180, then it moves in the opposite direction). I read the Wikipedia article which states : `The function atan2 (y,x) is defined as the angle in the Euclidean plane, given in radians, between the positive x axis and the ray to the point (x, y) ≠ (0, 0).`

I'm having difficulty understanding how the angle between two points would be calculated using atan2. Can someone explain this with a visual example?

Edit: I'm calculating the angle in Python using the following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735499/calculate-angle-clockwise-between-two-points) which calculates the clockwise angle between two points:

````
import numpy as np

def angle_between(p1, p2):
    x = 0
    ang1 = np.arctan2(*p1[::-1])
    ang2 = np.arctan2(*p2[::-1])
    return np.rad2deg((ang1 - ang2) % (2 * np.pi))
```
````

Comment: @YuriyS: Lots of programming languages. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2.

Comment: @YuriyS, it’s a standard implementation of arctan for computer programmers.

Comment: @user42: “The angle between two points” isn't a meaningful concept. Could you try to clarify your question? Note that in the definition they talk about the angle between two *rays* emanating from the origin.

Comment: @YuriyS See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Comment: @HansLundmark, I have clarified my question

Comment: We can easily come up with visual examples of the use of atan2, but they may not match what you need. I suggest that **you** show **us** a visual example of what it is that you want to calculate. For example: show two particular points on a graph (writing the numeric coordinates of the points, e.g. $(-2,3.5)$); explain how these two points relate to the object's motion; show the result you want (actual number of degrees or radians, e.g. $53^\circ$). This might give us some clues about what you think the direction of a moving object is and what the angle between two points is.

Comment: Personally I would never use that piece of code to describe a direction of motion; it seems to be answering a completely different question. But perhaps you're thinking of something completely different than I am.

Comment: @DavidK, you're right, if my object can move in all directions I cannot use it. But if the object is moving only left or right, can't I check if the angle is > 180 to determine if it is moving in the opposite direction?

Comment: If your object is constrained to move only left or right along a line that is known to you, then I don't see any need for angles. Increased $x$ coordinate $\implies$ rightward motion, decreasing $x$ coordinate $\implies$ leftward motion. Everything depends on what kind of constraints you have, what kind of information you have, and what the numbers signify.